# OpenCV: How to create a bird's eye view from four fish eye cameras?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to create a 360-degree bird's eye view around a car using images from the Oxford Robot Car Dataset. I have been able to demosaic and undistort the images using the camera model from the Python SDK provided by the dataset, but I'm stuck on finding the right destination and source points for my images for the inverse perspective mapping.

The camera setup consists of a Point Grey Bumblebee XB3 trinocular stereo camera with a 1280 × 960 resolution and a 66-degree HFoV, as well as three Point Grey Grasshopper2 monocular cameras with a 1024 × 1024 resolution, an 11.1 Hz frame rate, and a 180-degree HFoV. The monocular cameras have a 2.67mm fisheye lens, while the stereo camera has a 3.8mm lens.

The camera locations in relation to the car are shown in this diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlmUD.png

I have undistorted images from each camera, and I have the following information about each camera's intrinsic parameters:

Mono Left:

```
Focal Length: (400.0, 400.0)
Principal Point: (500.107605, 511.461426)
```

Mono Right:

```
Focal Length: (400.0, 400.0)
Principal Point: (502.503754, 490.259033)
```

Mono Rear:

```
Focal Length: (400.0, 400.0)
Principal Point: (508.222931, 498.187378)
```

Stereo Centre:

```
Focal Length: (964.828979, 964.828979)
Principal Point: (643.788025, 484.40799)
```

I have tried using getPerspectiveTransform from OpenCV, but I am not able to correctly choose the source and destination points.

Can anyone provide me with guidance on how to choose the correct points for the inverse perspective mapping and achieve my goal of creating a 360-degree bird's eye view around the car with a resolution of 800x800?

Answer (score 0):

Undistorting is, simulating "if ideal pinhole camera was located at the position the fish-eye camera was located, what image captured by the pinhole camera?".
Here, location of 2 camera is same, but how about orientation?

If you give the orientation of the virtual pinhole camera as vertical downword, result image will become the "bird's eye view".

What you should do is projecting all "bird's eye view" images from 4 cameras to single common plane (e.g. ground plane).

Generally, for such image warping process, what to calculate is inverted. (direction becomes to from result to input).
Therefore, For each pixel in your 800x800 result image, you need to calculate location on fish-eye image correspond to the result pixel location.
i.e. Consider 800x800 resolution image which lying on ground plane, and for each pixel of this image, calculate ray direction (pixel's 3D position to camera position), and then, calculate projection (from ray direction to fish-eye camera image pixel) based on camera parameter.